# Rails: How to increment counter_cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vote, counter-cache

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::: SOLVED :::

Was able to figure out counter_cache on the Vote model and use it in Topics.  Updated question below.  Once the Topic model had a votes_count, all I had to do was put that in the view and update my counting in the controllers.  Turned out to be pretty simple.  However finding information was not, so this should help others out, in all its confusing glory. Go way way down for the answer.

Cheers

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:::EDIT:::

:::See below for history:::

This is an edit to the original post.  I'm really close with what I have, before I try a gem solution.  I used a **comment_cache** on the **vote model** but now I don't know how to increment the cache.

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :topic, :counter_cache => true
end
```

and called topic.votes.size in the view and it now shows the count without an Active Record enumerable.

```
<td><%= pluralize(topic.votes.size, "vote") %></td>
        <td><%= button_to '+1', upvote_topic_path(topic), method: :post %></td>
        <td><%= button_to '-1', downvote_topic_path(topic), method: :post %></td>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
Listing Topics

Title   
test    1 vote  [+1] [-1]   Delete

New Topic
```

But comment_cache doesn't allow negative numbers.  I'm still using create/destroy on the records rather than adding and subtracting a number to the count.  How to increment and decrement?  Those methods say I'm missing values.  Currently it makes sense @topic.votes.last.destroy fails in that there are no more votes to destroy thus the tally cannot be less than zero.

How to setup so that I'm incrementing/decrementing the comment_cache value such that negative numbers are possible?  I tried @topic.votes.increment and @topic.votes.increment_counter but they ask for 2 params that I'm not sure what to use.  Tried

`@topic.increment_counter(:votes_count, params[:id])`

but no luck.

```
NoMethodError in TopicsController#upvote
undefined method `increment_counter' for #<Topic:0x007f87d974a4b0>

Extracted source (around line #433):
431
432
433
434
435
436

      else
        match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
      end
    end
```

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:::HISTORY BELOW THIS LINE:::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Revisiting Rails again and I'm trying to do a simple vote counter on topics.  What I want to do is increment/decrement the tally (integer) column in the votes record.

Topic has_may :votes, and Vote belongs_to :topic

In the ***topics_controller.rb*** I've used

```
def upvote
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @topic.votes.increment_counter(:tally, params[:id])
    redirect_to(topics_path)
  end

  def downvote
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @topic.votes.decrement_counter(:tally, params[:id])
    redirect_to(topics_path)
  end
```

But I get an interesting ActiveRecord key instead of a value in the view instead of the count of votes.

***index.html.erb:***

```
from the view
<td><%= pluralize(topic.votes(:tally), "vote") %></td>
<td><%= button_to '+1', upvote_topic_path(topic), method: :post %></td>
<td><%= button_to '-1', downvote_topic_path(topic), method: :post %></td>

result of view
    test    #<Vote::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbb16451f68> votes   

        Delete
```

From ***Rails Console*** though the increment doesn't show up:

```
  2.1.5 :022 > Vote.first
  Vote Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "votes".* FROM "votes"  ORDER BY "votes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => nil 

2.1.5 :023 > Vote
 => Vote(id: integer, topic_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, tally: integer)
```

I think I've setup the ***routes.rb*** ok but the double do I'm not sure about

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :topics do
    member do
      post 'upvote'
      post 'downvote'
    end
  end

  root 'topics#index'  
end
```

Anyway I think it's either the wrong method to increment or something I'm missing.  Any help appreciated.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

::SOLVED::

I was able to fix the problem using counter_cache in the Vote model.  Voting is now possible with both positive and negative values. Hooray!

Added a new column in topic.

```
class AddVotesCount < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :topics, :votes_count, :integer, :default => 0

  end
end
```

Update Vote model

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :topic, :counter_cache :true
end
```

Now in the topics controller I can increment the up/down methods with

```
@topic.votes_count += 1
.
.
.
@topic.votes_count -= 1
```

I can use @topic.update_attributes but I found it unreliable for some reason so I opted for @topic.save in each method.

The view now uses just topics.votes_count and works great.

```
<td><%= pluralize(topic.votes_count, "vote") %></td>
        <td><%= button_to '+1', upvote_topic_path(topic), method: :post %></td>
        <td><%= button_to '-1', downvote_topic_path(topic), method: :post %></td>
```

This works without needing a User model and/or the acts_as_votable gem.  Although I will probably use a gem in future it was good to figure out how to make this work without it.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I'm going to have a try as it would be good to know an alternate method to acts as votable

Comment: Don't know if it is something you're interested in? But you can drop a cookie, to stop somebody spamming votes... Have it check for a cookie that says they have voted before the vote count changes - if it doesn't exist cast the vote and then drop the cookie =D

Comment: Yes that sounds possible.  In my case I was thinking of doing an IP check on the vote.  So if the same IP wants to vote again it would just reject it.  Or if it wants to change its vote then to allow it.  That way it's not cookie/javascript limited.

Comment: This would be pretty awesome, but would it not affect offices and accommodations that share an external IP address? For example, if my colleague upvoted the topic, wouldn't my downvote subsequently remove it? As our external IP addresses would be the same...

Comment: Yes.  I thought about it and the odds of two people with the same IP caring to vote on the same things are proportionally going to be trolling companies instead of people.  The side effect is that those of offices and households can't vote more than once but I figure that's fine.  I could be even more restrictive by using IP Blocks ;)

Comment: BTW as I cannot upvote my own solution, please feel free to do so if you found it useful.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a user model working the votes? If so, there is a pretty awesome gem that handles this called `acts_as_votable` - https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

You just bundle the gem, run the migrations, then add `acts_as_votable` to your topics model, and `acts_as_voter` to your user model, you can then use a load of helper methods.

TopicsController.rb

```
    def upvote
        @topic.upvote_by current_user
        redirect_to :back
    end

    def downvote
        @topic.downvote_by current_user
        redirect_to :back
    end
```

Routes.rb

```
    resources :topics do
      member do
        get "upvote", to: "topics#upvote"
        get "downvote", to: "topics#downvote"
      end
    end
```

/topics/show.html.erb

```
    <%= link_to upvote_topic_path(@topic), method: :get  do %>
    <%= link_to downvote_topic_path(@topic), method: :get  do %>

    <%= pluralize(@topic.get_upvotes.size, 'Vote') %>
```

Comment: No user model yet.  I had tried this earlier but AaV wants to use its own vote model for itself so it gave me an error.  I'd have to drop the vote table then run it again I suppose.  

Before I go there though, I'd prefer to know how to increment a count in a model from the MVC in general terms before I get into more gems.

Comment: I figured it out for my case.  Thanks for your code as it gave me the idea to look at the model methods.  This lead me to counter_cache.  Then I had to fix up my code.  Then boom, solved.  Thanks!